# Create json object from JsonSchema4

Tags: jsonschema, njsonschema

I have a complex Json Schema having  properties and their definitions, I know the root property, Using jsonSchema4, how can I create the complete object for the root property that includes its nested dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You mean how to write JSON schemas easier, right? You may use [joi-to-json-schema](https://github.com/lightsofapollo/joi-to-json-schema)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I meant, I already had the JSON Schema, I want to create the object out of that schema, I know the root element within the schema, now I need to traverse from the root element to each and every dependencies and create the object. The one you suggested talks about creating the Schema.

Comment: @UmeshKanyal: Well, personally I will use [mongoose schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) to create a model (or the object ) to work with. To convert json-schema to mongoose schema, you may use [mongoose-from-json-schema](https://github.com/work-in-progress/mongoose-from-json-schema). Is that ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [json-schema-faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-faker)